# How to conditionally save scrapy results with IF statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to generate some urls dynamically and crawl the **generated addresses**.
 The shell command which I use here, will generate 128 different URLs in every single query and save them in a txt file. Which then I will use every line in the text file to use as a scrapy URL. 
Now, I want to **save the page address as output only if it have an element with a specific value on the page rather than ZERO**.

So far, I have created a scrapy crawler which is now successfully generating the txt files and extract each line and build the URLs.
And it's crawling them without any problem as I see.

```
import json
import uuid
import os
import re
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import subprocess

class ItemSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawler"
    def start_requests(self):
        for count in range(1, 200):
            calling = 'keys-generator kml ' + str(count) + ' >C:/scrapy/crawler/keypages/keypage' + str(count) +'.txt'
            subprocess.call(calling, shell=True)
            with open('C:/scrapy/crawler/keypages/keypage' + str(count) +'.txt', 'r') as j:
                kmlkeys = j.readlines()
                kmlkeys = [x.strip() for x in kmlkeys]
                for x in kmlkeys:
                    comkey = re.sub(r'([^\s]+) ', '', x)
                    comkey2 = re.sub(r' [^ ]+$', '', comkey)
                    comkey3 = re.sub(r'}', '', comkey2)
                    url = 'https://www.example.com/kml/' + comkey3
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            os.remove('C:/scrapy/crawler/keypages/keypage' + str(count) +'.txt')
    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.xpath('//*'):
            bb = item.xpath('//*[@id="fb"]/font/span/text()').extract()
            tb = item.xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/font/span/text()').extract()
            if (tb != "0 KML"):
                with open('C:/scrapy/crawler/FOUND.txt', 'a') as fp:
                    fp.write(response.url)
```

I expect the crawler save the response URLs which only if they have non 0 value. But it's saving all of them without any attention to the IF statement I used here.

Comment: What are typical values of tb? Doesn't `extract()` return a list, in which case it will never be equal to a string? How about replacing `if (tb != "0 KML"):` with `if tb:`?

Comment: Did you check the `tb` value?

Comment: @ArunAugustine yes, when I use print inside if statement, it prints all values including zero ones. for example, it prints like this : ['0.01 KML'] and also ['0 KML'] . I want to save only values which is not 0 KML. It seems that IF statement is not working here.

Comment: @M.Safari: Read about [extract-and-extract-first](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first)

Comment: @stovfl it's not about extracting the first value or the others, it's about why IF statement is not working here.

Comment: @stovfl it returns all Ture

Comment: @M.Safari: But you expected it to be `False`! Therefore use `.extract_first()` and your condition becomes: `if '0 KML' != "0 KML": == False`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of `tb` values, make sure that its string type. then try

```
if str(tb) == "0 KML":
    pass
else:
    with open('C:/scrapy/crawler/FOUND.txt', 'a') as fp:
        fp.write(response.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally find a solution for this.
Here is how I fixed it:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for item in response.xpath('//*'):
        bb = item.xpath('//*[@id="fb"]/font/span/text()').extract()
        tb = item.xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/font/span[contains(., "0 KML")]/text()').extract()
    if not tb:
        do something...
```